# rebol --do doesn't work?

Tags: rebol

According to this
http://www.rebol.com/docs/changes.html#section-1.7

--do should work again

but when I tested on Rebview 1.3.2 / Core 2.6.3
rebol.exe helloworld.exe --do "verbose: true"

with helloworld.r:

```
probe verbose
input
```

This triggers an error

** Script Error: verbose has no value
** Near: probe verbose
input

So does it work again or not finally ? :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The interpreter is sensitive to the order of the command line options. **do** before **script name** works for me:

```
   rebview  --do "verbose: true" helloworld.r
```

where **helloworld.r** is:

```
  rebol []
  probe verbose
  input
  halt
```

I see a REBOL console output of:

```
 true
```